After installation with playonlinux, the game does not appear
I use Linux Mint 22 and have Rollercoaster Tycoon Deluxe from GOG.
I could install it with playonlinux and right after installation, the game could can be started. So I did it and could play and even save games.
But when I quit the game (or do not start it right away after installation), there is no entry in my list.
Even if I do wine RCT.exe in the folder where it is installed to, it starts, but without sound.
Only if I install it again and then start it, I can play.
What can I do?

This looks like a known bug with wine. Link to WineHQ
Seems like there is a partial workaround with installing quartz using winetricks, or PlayOnLinux interface.
Another solution would be to install gstreamer packages. I will post a link to the AppDB again, where the "Platinum" version of the game has been tested. Link

Workarounds
The workaround for the music is to install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-libav
gstreamer1.0-libav:i386
for under Ubuntu 20.04:
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-libav:i386
I think that this workaround is not working for older Ubuntu versions


Now PlayOnLinux is a mighty fine program, but sometimes games can be finicky getting set up right.
A couple things you could try - first go into the PlayOnLinux settings and make sure the game is configured to run as a shortcut instead of just through the terminal. Also double check file permissions on the install folder, just to be safe nothing's blocking it from launching proper. And if all else fails, might be worth reinstalling PlayOnLinux fresh and starting from scratch.
Let us know if any other ideas come to mind!
